# What attributes to apply laplace smoothing in naive bayes classifier?

Tags: self-study, data-mining, naive-bayes, laplace-smoothing

I am reading naive Bayes classifier from the book "Data mining practical machine learning tools and techniques". The example of naive Bayes is given using the below dataset.

[image: Weather data set]

As (**Outlook**=Overcast | **Play**=No) has 0 counts, the book suggests using Laplace smoothing. For this, I have to add 1 to numerator and 3 to the denominator (as there are 3 different outlooks. I understand this part).

Now my question is do I have to use Laplace smoothing on (**Outlook** | **Play**=Yes) too? Do I have to use Laplace smoothing for other attributes too? Or using Laplace smoothing on only the attributes that have 0 count enough? (in this case (**Outlook** | **Play**=No)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this is certainly too late to help you, but answering in case others find the question.

When using Laplace smoothing, you should apply the smoothing for **all attributes**.

To see why this is important, consider a dataset containing exactly 1 instance of a certain attribute and 0 instances of another. If you only applied the smoothing factor to the attribute with 0 instances, the result would be equal probabilities for the two attributes, even though there were more instances of the former. By adding 1 to all attributes, you make sure nothing has a complete 0% probability while also maintaining the correct relative likelihood.